# Min-max normalisation of a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy array:

```
foo = np.array([[0.0, 10.0], [0.13216, 12.11837], [0.25379, 42.05027], [0.30874, 13.11784]])
```

which yields:

```
[[  0.       10.     ]
 [  0.13216  12.11837]
 [  0.25379  42.05027]
 [  0.30874  13.11784]]
```

How can I normalize the Y component of this array. So it gives me something like:

```
[[  0.       0.   ]
 [  0.13216  0.06 ]
 [  0.25379  1    ]
 [  0.30874  0.097]]
```

Comment: How is this normalized?  How does `10.0` get normalized to `0`?

Comment: It is fit from the `10 - 42.05027` range to a `0 - 1` range. The numbers are made-up, but represent what I am looking for. 10 would be 0 as it is the lowest number.

Comment: Is this 'max-min' normalization?

Comment: Yes -> `normalized = (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))` I just could not get it to work with the more complex numpy data.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Referring to this Cross Validated Link, [How to normalize data to 0-1 range?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range), it looks like you can perform min-max normalisation on the last column of `foo`.

```
v = foo[:, 1]   # foo[:, -1] for the last column
foo[:, 1] = (v - v.min()) / (v.max() - v.min())
```

```
foo

array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.13216   ,  0.06609523],
       [ 0.25379   ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.30874   ,  0.09727968]])
```

---

Another option for performing normalisation (as suggested by OP) is using `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`, which yields slightly different results -

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
foo[:, [-1]] = normalize(foo[:, -1, None], norm='max', axis=0)
```

```
foo

array([[ 0.        ,  0.2378106 ],
       [ 0.13216   ,  0.28818769],
       [ 0.25379   ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.30874   ,  0.31195614]])
```

Answer (score 15):

[sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) can also be used (`feature_range=(0, 1)` is default):

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
v = foo[:,1]
v_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(v)
foo[:,1] = v_scaled
print(foo)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.13216     0.06609523]
 [ 0.25379     1.        ]
 [ 0.30874     0.09727968]]
```

Advantage is that scaling to any range can be done.

Answer (score 8):

I think you want this:

```
foo[:,1] = (foo[:,1] - foo[:,1].min()) / (foo[:,1].max() - foo[:,1].min())
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to min-max scale between 0 and 1 only the second column.

Using [`sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale), should easily solve your problem.

e.g.:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

column_1 = foo[:,0] #first column you don't want to scale
column_2 = minmax_scale(foo[:,1], feature_range=(0,1)) #second column you want to scale
foo_norm = np.stack((column_1, column_2), axis=1) #stack both columns to get a 2d array
```

Should yield

```
array([[0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.13216   , 0.06609523],
       [0.25379   , 1.        ],
       [0.30874   , 0.09727968]])
```

---

Maybe you want to min-max scale between 0 and 1 both columns. In this case, use:

```
foo_norm = minmax_scale(foo, feature_range=(0,1), axis=0)
```

Which yields

```
array([[0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.42806245, 0.06609523],
       [0.82201853, 1.        ],
       [1.        , 0.09727968]])
```

**note**: Not to be confused with the operation that scales the [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) (length) of a vector to a certain value (usually 1), which is also commonly referred to as normalization.