# Normalize Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy array and I want to normalize its values. I used the following code but after normalization my data was corrupted. Is there a specific function for normalization?

How can I do it?

```
def preprocess(data):
     data=np.nan_to_num(data)  
     maximum=np.amax(data)
     minimum=np.amin(data)
     data=(data-minimum)/(maximum-minimum)  
     print(data)
     return data
```

**Data**:

[image: I added some of my data to show what they look like]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Min-max normalisation of a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178884/min-max-normalisation-of-a-numpy-array)

Comment: @CameronChandler .no I did this (According to the above code)but my data was currupted.I want another solution Or ready function.

Comment: Then your input is corrupted (whatever that means). Both, the linked code and your code work perfectly well.

Comment: I agree. You code runs fine if you want to normalize with respect to all the columns. Please check your input data?  Also, what is your input data looks like? What is the shape of it? you want to normalize the whole array or each columns separately?

Comment: @Grayrigel I have a column containing 300 different numbers that after applying this code, the output is completely zero.what's the problem?

Comment: @Mr.T I added some of my data to show what they look like.please check it

Comment: [Well.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Mr.T I did not understand what you meant

Comment: Don't post code, data as images. It is rather well explained in the linked comment. Mainly: We don't know the datatype. Numpy behaves differently for strings, int, float but the image may look the same. However, looking at it - rather very large and very small numbers. While Python long values are not restricted, numpy data are. I don't remember exactly what the upper limit is for numpy float32, but you may want to look into this problem.

Comment: Yup. Looks like you collide with the maximum numpy can compute: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658752/8881141

Comment: @Mr.T I checked that my data is not out of this range

Comment: Are you sure that all values `(data-minimum)` are within those numpy limits?

Comment: @azin I noticed that the values are either very high or very low, which could have an impact on the calculation. Furthermore, are you dealing with numpy array or a dataframe.

Comment: @Grayrigel yes they are very high or low..But I only have this data and yes They are numppy arrays/can you help me?i need to normalize them.what can i do?

Comment: @azin Can you post the data in the text form?

Comment: @Grayrigel I don't know how???

Comment: @azin Perhaps upload some part on the google drive and share the link. This is need so that I can copy-paste and work with the exact data.

Comment: @Grayrigel Is it possible to email the data to you?

Comment: @azin Instead of sending an email, it would be better if you upload data on google/onedrive/dropbox and sharing the viewable link here.

Comment: @Grayrigel I don't know haw can i do this but I got my data ready from a site. Can I send the link?

Comment: @Grayrigel I sent it to you.thanks

Comment: @azin where is the data which you shared here? I see several folders containing hea and bin files.

Comment: @Grayrigel it does not matter you can choose one of folders.and my data is the bin file.
I'm trying to normalize that data.I read the bin file and converted it to float64...And then I tried to normalize

Comment: @azin we will continue the discussion on the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are looking for alternatives**, one possible option is to use [`MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) from `scikit-learn`. Here is an example (**Note that this normalizes each column**):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

>>> data = np.random.random((10,2))
>>> sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
>>> data_norm = sc.fit_transform(data)

>>> data_norm
array([[1.        , 0.04518975],
       [0.09360991, 1.        ],
       [0.94696839, 0.28945529],
       [0.43489412, 0.        ],
       [0.47447027, 0.53392371],
       [0.59116035, 0.82860749],
       [0.81434593, 0.78785469],
       [0.        , 0.03156277],
       [0.51659277, 0.06002646],
       [0.82566529, 0.67091873]])
```

As @Mr.T already mentioned in the comment, your code runs fine, it normalizes the data **with respect to the whole array**. Here is what I mean:

```
>>> data_norm = sc.fit_transform(data.reshape(-1,1)).reshape(-1,data.shape[1])
>>> data_norm

>>> data_norm
array([[0.94871152, 0.04518975],
       [0.09136079, 1.        ],
       [0.89854913, 0.28945529],
       [0.41418014, 0.        ],
       [0.45161507, 0.53392371],
       [0.56199174, 0.82860749],
       [0.77310208, 0.78785469],
       [0.00281555, 0.03156277],
       [0.49145857, 0.06002646],
       [0.78380902, 0.67091873]])
```

Running your code gives:

```
>>> data_norm = preprocess(data)
>>> data_norm
array([[0.94871152, 0.04518975],
       [0.09136079, 1.        ],
       [0.89854913, 0.28945529],
       [0.41418014, 0.        ],
       [0.45161507, 0.53392371],
       [0.56199174, 0.82860749],
       [0.77310208, 0.78785469],
       [0.00281555, 0.03156277],
       [0.49145857, 0.06002646],
       [0.78380902, 0.67091873]])
```

Comment: I entered the first code you said but this error was shown in other parts of the *program:operands could not be broadcast together with shapes*.what can i do?

Comment: Your data doesn't look like a numpy array, if it is a pandas dataframes, you need to `data = data.to_numpy()`